# Python encode issue with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, beautifulsoup

Hello I`ve got a problem which encoding

When I put string to beautifulsoup lost all National char

```
addr = "http://zjazdowa.com.pl/index.php/aktualne-ceny-warzyw-i-owocow-.html"                                
content = urllib2.urlopen(addr) .read()
html_pag = BeautifulSoup(content) #<- there i lost all national letters 
table_html= html_pag.find("div",  id="808")
```

In the header file I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, string, re , sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: The code you've posted works, and retains all "National" characters.

Answer (score 4):

according to the documentation of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) all the input is transformed to UTF8 internally:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("Hello")
soup.contents[0]
# u'Hello'
soup.originalEncoding
# 'ascii'
```

if your input does not specify the encoding (eg, meta-tags), BeautifulSoup guesses. you can disable the guessing by specifying the encoding of the input via the `fromEncoding`paramter to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("hello", fromEncoding="UTF-8")
```

or is your real problem the 'broken' output of the result to the console?

Comment: FYI: His webpage specifies the encoding correctly, using both a Content-Type header and a <meta> tag. I'd guess your "real problem" guess is what the actual problem is…

Comment: note that fromEncoding was renamed to from_encoding in BeautifulSoup 4

Answer (score 1):

And your code works perfectly fine:

```
>>> addr = "http://zjazdowa.com.pl/index.php/aktualne-ceny-warzyw-i-owocow-.html"                                
>>> content = urllib2.urlopen(addr) .read()
>>> html_pag = BeautifulSoup(content) #<- there i lost all national letters 
>>> table_html= html_pag.find("div",  id="808")
>>> print table_html.findAll('td')[8].string
Kapusta włoska
```

A few notes on this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, string, re , sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

`reload` reloads a module. I'm not sure what you're hoping to do by reloading `sys`, but it isn't buying you anything.